# orika mapping error exists in Bytecode

Tags: mapping, runtime-error, bytecode, orika

I am trying to include orika in my project.
I have BaseEntity & BaseEntityDAO classes which got only Id column.
And those inherited by BaseAuditEntity & BaseAuditEntityDTO classes respectively. These classes have audit columns like created by, created_date, updated_by, updated_datetime.
Then these classes inherited by actual Entity and DTO classes depened whether they got audit columns or not.

I have a BaseServiceBean which takes ParameterizedTypes and have base CRUD implementations. So here I have taken conside [this](https://code.google.com/p/orika/source/browse/branches/examples/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/examples/?r=404#examples/library/mapping) example from orika documentation.
So my problem is I am getting following error message when it is actually mapping the data.....

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent args count operand in invokeinterface
```

Exception Details:
  Location:
    ma/glasnost/orika/generated/Orika_UsersDTO_Users_Mapper25974687500962$0.mapAtoB(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lma/glasnost/orika/MappingContext;)V @59: invokeinterface
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b 2c2d b700 0c2b c000 0e3a 042c c000
    0000010: 103a 0519 04b6 0016 c000 1801 a500 2d19
    0000020: 052a b400 1e03 32c0 0020 1904 b600 16c0
    0000030: 0018 2ab4 0024 0332 c000 26b9 002a 0400
    0000040: c000 2cb6 0032 a700 0919 0501 b600 3219
    0000050: 04b6 0036 c000 3801 a500 2d19 052a b400
    0000060: 1e04 32c0 0020 1904 b600 36c0 0038 2ab4
    0000070: 0024 0432 c000 26b9 002a 0400 c000 38b6
    0000080: 003c a700 0919 0501 b600 3c19 0519 04b6
    0000090: 003f c000 18b6 0043 1905 1904 b600 46c0
    00000a0: 0018 b600 4919 0519 04b6 004c c000 18b6
    00000b0: 004f 1905 1904 b600 52c0 0018 b600 5519
    00000c0: 0519 04b6 005b c000 2cb6 0060 1905 1904
    00000d0: b600 63c0 0018 b600 6619 0519 04b6 0069
    00000e0: c000 18b6 006c 1905 1904 b600 6fc0 0018
    00000f0: b600 7219 0519 04b6 0075 c000 18b6 0078
    0000100: 1905 1904 b600 7bc0 0018 b600 7e19 04b6
    0000110: 0081 c000 1801 a500 2d19 052a b400 1e03
    0000120: 32c0 0020 1904 b600 81c0 0018 2ab4 0024
    0000130: 0332 c000 26b9 002a 0400 c000 2cb6 0084
    0000140: a700 0919 0501 b600 8419 04b6 0087 c000
    0000150: 3801 a500 2d19 052a b400 1e04 32c0 0020
    0000160: 1904 b600 87c0 0038 2ab4 0024 0432 c000
    0000170: 26b9 002a 0400 c000 38b6 008a a700 0919
    0000180: 0501 b600 8a19 0519 04b6 008d c000 18b6
    0000190: 0090 1905 1904 b600 93c0 0018 b600 962a
    00001a0: b400 9a01 a500 112a b400 9a19 0419 052d
    00001b0: b900 9d04 00b1
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@73,Object[#14],Object[#16])
    same_frame(@79)
    same_frame(@133)
    same_frame(@139)
    same_frame_extended(@323)
    same_frame(@329)
    same_frame(@383)
    same_frame(@389)
    same_frame(@437)

```
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent args count operand in invokeinterface
Exception Details:
  Location:
    ma/glasnost/orika/generated/Orika_UsersDTO_Users_Mapper25974687500962$0.mapAtoB(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lma/glasnost/orika/MappingContext;)V @59: invokeinterface
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b 2c2d b700 0c2b c000 0e3a 042c c000
    0000010: 103a 0519 04b6 0016 c000 1801 a500 2d19
    0000020: 052a b400 1e03 32c0 0020 1904 b600 16c0
    0000030: 0018 2ab4 0024 0332 c000 26b9 002a 0400
    0000040: c000 2cb6 0032 a700 0919 0501 b600 3219
    0000050: 04b6 0036 c000 3801 a500 2d19 052a b400
    0000060: 1e04 32c0 0020 1904 b600 36c0 0038 2ab4
    0000070: 0024 0432 c000 26b9 002a 0400 c000 38b6
    0000080: 003c a700 0919 0501 b600 3c19 0519 04b6
    0000090: 003f c000 18b6 0043 1905 1904 b600 46c0
    00000a0: 0018 b600 4919 0519 04b6 004c c000 18b6
    00000b0: 004f 1905 1904 b600 52c0 0018 b600 5519
    00000c0: 0519 04b6 005b c000 2cb6 0060 1905 1904
    00000d0: b600 63c0 0018 b600 6619 0519 04b6 0069
    00000e0: c000 18b6 006c 1905 1904 b600 6fc0 0018
    00000f0: b600 7219 0519 04b6 0075 c000 18b6 0078
    0000100: 1905 1904 b600 7bc0 0018 b600 7e19 04b6
    0000110: 0081 c000 1801 a500 2d19 052a b400 1e03
    0000120: 32c0 0020 1904 b600 81c0 0018 2ab4 0024
    0000130: 0332 c000 26b9 002a 0400 c000 2cb6 0084
    0000140: a700 0919 0501 b600 8419 04b6 0087 c000
    0000150: 3801 a500 2d19 052a b400 1e04 32c0 0020
    0000160: 1904 b600 87c0 0038 2ab4 0024 0432 c000
    0000170: 26b9 002a 0400 c000 38b6 008a a700 0919
    0000180: 0501 b600 8a19 0519 04b6 008d c000 18b6
    0000190: 0090 1905 1904 b600 93c0 0018 b600 962a
    00001a0: b400 9a01 a500 112a b400 9a19 0419 052d
    00001b0: b900 9d04 00b1
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@73,Object[#14],Object[#16])
    same_frame(@79)
    same_frame(@133)
    same_frame(@139)
    same_frame_extended(@323)
    same_frame(@329)
    same_frame(@383)
    same_frame(@389)
    same_frame(@437)

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.getInstance(SourceCodeContext.java:264)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:72)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1190)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.lookupMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:651)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.lookupMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:609)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.resolveMapper(MapperFacadeImpl.java:531)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.resolveMappingStrategy(MapperFacadeImpl.java:206)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:694)
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:675)
at za.co.insa.service.UsersServiceBean.getEntityDTO(UsersServiceBean.java:21)
at za.co.insa.service.UsersServiceBean.getEntityDTO(UsersServiceBean.java:15)
at za.co.insa.service.BaseServiceBean.findAll(BaseServiceBean.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy278.findAll(Unknown Source)
at za.co.insa.utils.LoginController.doLogin(LoginController.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 68 more
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to map from Entity to DTO after getting Entity from the DB.

Comment: Do you have stale classfiles? Try recompiling everything.

Comment: I have deleted the cache files and restarted net beans still giving me the same error. Is it something to do with abstract classes or interfaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that orika has some dependencies and I have to add them in pom.xml.

```
<!-- Orika-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
        <artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-sizeof</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Abover mentioned are the dependecies. Don't know which one exactly solves the problem and doesn't know whether we need all these.

Thanks